# iCloud Service on Windows10 keep High CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, icloud

When I installed iCloud Tool on windows10 to sync photo,Browser Bookmark etc. with my iOS device and Mac ,I found iCloud service and Apple push process always occupied very High cpu usage, it often Up to 100% usage. What's the reason of this problem? How to resolve it ?Thanks!

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: @Neil Thanks,But now I do not use iTunes an iCloud on windows any more.Thanks all the same.

Comment: 2023 still the same issue, lol. I think Apple being Apple?

Comment: @EyalCohen, I have moved to macOS for a long time,it never bother me any more. Lol